# How to use C# client to get information of clicked GUI element in another app?

Tags: c#, c++, spy++, event-hooking

Can a C# client record all keyboard and mouse events using hooks and collect information on the clicked GUI element?

Which libary would you use?

Is Spy++ an option or would one need a C++ DLL for that?

Comment: you can't use spy in your application, it's a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do it in c++, you should register your hook, then you can create a bridge, but in C# may be [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx) article is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. [See here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) and [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) It's called event hooking.

You don't need any special library. Also, Spy++ is a standalone app that does this. Are you looking to write something like it with .NET?

Comment: Thanks will have a look. Indeed I'd like to have some of the Spy++ features in my .net client.

Comment: The first article says: Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework, except for two (MouseLL, KeyboardLL). From what I understand the hook just get me the event, but not the info on the GUI element.

Comment: From the event you get the window handle and from that any GUI element (all Win32 UI elements have a window handle.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Deskperience and their Screen Scraper Studio product. Offers you a trial with the SDK.

Im trying to emulate their functionality at the moment, but finding it hard to do as Im a one man show...

[Link to Deskperience Website](http://screen-scraper.deskperience.com/features?source=google&gclid=CMTZ34Xis6YCFcqs7QodI2SVHQ)

Answer (score 0):

You have this [lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx), which is specially useful for managed apps. I'm not so sure how it interacts with non managed code though.

Comment: Thanks, this is ManagedSpyLib is indeed for managed code only.

Answer (score 0):

UISpy.exe is a tool using .net Automation Framework and will allow you to experiment with what you can automate in C#.

Along with lower level keyboard and mouse hooks as described by [Paul Sasik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391980/how-to-use-c-client-to-get-information-of-clicked-gui-element-in-another-app/4392055#4392055) in this question,  you can translate the screen location into a .net automation object and gain additional info about what is being clicked or typed at.

Comment: It seems very complicated to get hold off UISpy.exe to you have a download link?

Comment: It's in the Platform or Framework SDK, the biggest problem is they keep leaving it out for some reason.  I found [this site](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2009/09/15/uispy-ndash-download-it-here.aspx) that seems to have a good copy